# How to avoid select .apk file extension

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I Try code for a open Documentation File but Also it's take a **.apk** File

**How to avoid .apk extension** Other wise This code work perfect to select other document

See Below Code for a Open Documentation File:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.rlSelectFile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("application/x-excel|application/pdf|text/plain|text/csv|image/*");
                //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);*/
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Not Only .apk but also How to avoid any Extension**

Comment: I don't have any idea why use `mimeType` so i put this line in a comment. I'll Just a paste this code it's work file but it's also select a .apk file but i not need to catch a .apk file @pskink

Comment: @MohammadAli Do you know have the file details before opening?

Comment: No but i need only avoid .apk file @udit7395

Comment: By file details I mean the file name and path ?

Comment: When i open a my folder it's show pdf, txt, excel, apk etc or Image or some other extension it can't show @udit7395